# Me gustaría que pulse una modal con KATALON

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

me gustaría que pulsará este botón de una modal y genere el archivo, este es el codigo:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')
WebUI.navigateToUrl('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
WebUI.click('CGXX/clickCalendario')
WebUI.click(findTestObject('CGXX/clickCalendario'), '17/06/2019')
WebUI.click('CGXX/clickPulsar')
WebUI.click('CGXX/clickImg')
WebUI.switchToWindowsTitle('Abriendo C-48_Castellano_v1.0_Maquetacion.pdf')

/// no hace caso cuando pulsa, todo lo de arriba me hace caso
WebUI.click('Abrir con')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si es una descarga tendras que gestionar las opciones del browser. Para indicarle que no abra ese modal para las descargas del browser.

Si usas Firefox, por ejemplo, las opciones serian la siguientes:

```
// Creo el profile donde asociaremos las extensiones por las que no queremos preguntar al descargar
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);  
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
        "text/csv,application/java-archive, application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,"
            + "application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,"
            + "application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable,application/json");
// Creo las opciones que permite personalizar el navegador
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(profile);

FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```